# indexing of nested lists in python

Tags: python, indexing, nested-lists

The core Problem:
I have paths saved as a triple nested lists and I fail to index them properly.

Explaining the list in question:
The first dimension is the number of paths. Each path is a list that represent the values at the different timesteps. Each timestep is a list, where every timestep has a different dimension, which is the reason I have a tripple nested list and not a matrix.

Since this is very confusing here is an example:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YaS4.png)

For this example my val paths are saved in h1 (usually multiple hundred, I reduced it to 2 for this example).
I have expanded the first path and you can see that at time k it consists of all values up to time k.

The problem is that I want a single line code that remove all timesteps after k for all paths.

To me it seemed very simple as "[:][:k]" should do it, however it doesn't change the list at all (see h2 == h1). As stuff like [:, :k] doesn't work either I am quite confused.

Update:
Here is a minimal example

```
l1 = []
l11 = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
l12 = [[5], [5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
l1.append(l11)
l1.append(l12)

# Goal:
l_target = [[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]], [[5], [5, 6], [5, 6, 7]]]

print(l1[:][:4] == l_target)
```

Comment: Please create an [mcve] and show us your code as code and not in an image link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: You haven't *written* a line of code that would remove anything, or "change the list at all".

Comment: Lists are filled with references to the objects they contain. If you make a shallow copy with  `[:]` the lists nested below are still the same.

Comment: I have updated an example, is that sufficient?